# How to resolve ipython (show) install error

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to install show on linux and am getting the following error:

```
sudo pip install show
...
Collecting ipython (from show)
Downloading ipython-6.1.0.tar.gz (5.1MB)
100% |████████████████████████████████| 5.1MB 89kB/s
Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 20, in <module

----------------------------------------
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-xYQAaZ/ipython
```

There is no such file/dir /tmp/pip-build-xYQAaZ/ipython so I don't have any more details.  Any ideas how to debug this further or resolve the install issue?  I'm on python 2.6.6.  I was able to install show on another linux system with python 2.6.6 without any issues.

Answer (score 0):

I had similar issues installing a python package (had the same error code). What eventually worked was installing the wheel. First install support for wheels by doing `pip install wheel` and then you can download the wheel file from [here](http://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#numpy) and install it using `pip install ____`

Answer (score 0):

IPython 6 [supports Python 3.3+ only](http://blog.jupyter.org/2017/04/19/release-of-ipython-6-0/).
To install a supported version of IPython, you should first use `pip install "ipython<6"`.

Note that this condition should not be required if `pip` is up to date.